# Google map shows incorrect location using GPRS

Tags: android, geolocation, gps

I am developing an android application which shows the user's current location. The map shows the correct location when using wifi, but it shows the wrong location in GPRS and in offline mode. I followed this [Android GPS, Location Manager Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/).

How can I make this work for GPRS and offline mode too?

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;
String addressString;
GoogleMap map;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude
double accuracy;

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);


        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            onLocationChanged(location);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }       
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/*
 * Function to get accuracy
 * 
 */

public double getAccuracy(){
    if(location != null){
        accuracy = location.getAccuracy();
    }
    return accuracy;

}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}



/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if(location.hasAccuracy()) {
        latitude  = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}``

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
```

In my Activity class:

```
 gps = new GPSTracker(PM_Start_Loc.this);

 if(gps.canGetLocation()){



        latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        longitude = gps.getLongitude();

        distance=gps.getAccuracy();

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


    getAddress(latitude, longitude);

        latlng=new LatLng(latitude, longitude);


     Log.d(WebServiceHelper.TAG, "Lattitude---->"+latitude);
     Log.d(WebServiceHelper.TAG, "Longitude---->"+longitude);
     Log.d(WebServiceHelper.TAG, "Address---->"+addressString);
     Log.d(WebServiceHelper.TAG, "acuracy---->"+distance);

   Marker m=map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng));
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng, 15.0f));

        shEditor.putString("sdeMarkedStartLocLat",""+latitude).commit();
        shEditor.putString("sdeMarkedStartLocLong",""+longitude).commit();

     }else{
        // can't get location
        // GPS or Network is not enabled
        // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
        gps.showSettingsAlert();
     }
```

Comment: Please upload the code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using GPS location would be best seeing it is most accurate.
In most cases, WIFI would me more accurate (Relying on modems and ISP's) then GPRS signal (relying on cell towers).

When offline - the app will use the last known location that is probably incorrect anyway.

Refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationProvider.html) too for further reading and implementing the code you want.